# Excel - custom number format as "## ### ####"

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a solution to format my number as folow : 123456789 -> 12 345 6789
When I try to use a custom format as "## ### ####" it's not working and Excel
return 123 456 789

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: You need to use this `## ### ####` **Or** `##\ ###\ ####` . Please check if there are non printable characters or not.

Comment: Thanks Mayukh, it's working with this second solution ##\ ###\ ####

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user defined number format `## ### ####` results in `123 456 789` for you, then the space is set to be the thousands separator in your system or your Excel. If so, then a simple space in a number format always means the thousands separator which separates thousands always and nothing else.

But you can use the user defined number format `##\ ###\ ####` or `##" "###" "####`. That uses the space character as a character independent of it's special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

On my PC this is working fine, as you can see:

[image]

I believe there might be a problem with your Excel version. I'm working with Excel 365.

As the thousands separator, I don't have the space character, but another one, as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: I also use Excel 365 and I tried on Excel Standard 2016 with the same result .... It's so weird

Comment: @Dominique: So in your system (or Excel) the space is **not** set to be the thousands separator.

Comment: @AxelRichter: indeed, it is not, as indicated in my edited answer.

Comment: @AxelRichter: I can also confirm that, if I do use the space as the thousand separator, that I have the same wrong behaviour as the author.

Comment: @Dominique: I would not call it a "wrong behaviour". If the thousands separator gets used in a number format, then it **should** separate the thousands and nothing else.